# e.target.value not defined in react useState

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, formik

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  password: yup
    .string('Enter your password')
    .min(8, 'Password should be of minimum 8 characters length')
    .required('Password is required'),
});
  
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      password: '',
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });


<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}  style={{ width:'100%' }}>
           
  <div className="relative w-full flex items-center">
    <RedditTextField
      fullWidth
      type={passwordType}
      className="mb-5"
      id="outlined-adornment-password"
      placeholder="Password"
      name="password"
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      error={formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)}
      helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
    />
  </div>
  <Button
      type="submit"
      // onClick={}
      variant="outlined"
      style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF5758', color: 'white', width: '100%', height: '50px', border: 'none' }}
      size="large"
      endIcon={!isLoading && <SendIcon />}
      loading={isLoading}
     >
          {isLoading ? "Fetching..." : "Sign Up"}
   </Button>

</form>
```

There are no errors at the form, but the sign up button doesn't submit the form, do you think all inputs and buttons should be direct children to the form tag itself?

Answer (score 1):

The `onSubmit` attribute on your `<form>` tag has the function `formik.handleSubmit`, but from the code, `formik` has an `onSubmit` function, not a `handleSubmit` function.

Try:

```
<form onSubmit={formik.onSubmit}  style={{ width:'100%' }}>
```

OR
change the function in `formik` to:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      password: '',
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
  handleSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });
```

Lemme know how it goes :)